# How to make the origin (0,0) point in flame engine in the bottom

Tags: flutter, flame

I want to make the origin point in the bottom-left corner instead of the top-left corner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily set the origin of the `World` to the bottom corner by moving the camera so that 0,0 of the `World` is in the bottom corner of the viewport, two different ways to do so are:

```dart
camera.position = Vector2(
  camera.viewport.size.x / 2,
  -camera.viewport.size.y / 2,
);
```

Or if you don't care about where the `viewfinder` anchor is, you can simply do this (if you are using the `follow` method, you probably don't want to do this):

```dart
camera.viewfinder.anchor = Anchor.bottomLeft;
```

Even though you're not stating it in your question, I'm guessing that you also want the flip the coordinate system, so that Y grows upwards instead of shrinks, this is much harder to achieve.